# How do you add data providers to the "Data Source Configuration Wizard" in VS2010

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, provider, paradox

How do you add data providers to the "Data Source Configuration Wizard"? I'd like to add Paradox to this list. Is it possible?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These providers are installed as part of some components - so you have to check if Paradox have ADO.NET provider. Otherwise you will have to use ODBC driver.